# MYSQL return data not including current month/year

Tags: mysql

I need to pull data from a table which has the dates stored in separate YEAR and MONTH columns...

I need to pull data only for the last two years...

Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT 
        st_year as YEAR,
        st_month as  MONTH,
        count(*) 
    FROM 
        V1_Stable
    WHERE 
        st_year IS NOT NULL 
    AND
        st_month IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        st_year,  st_month
    ORDER BY YEAR ASC, MONTH ASC;
```

Basically, that gets me the data I need, but I need to limit it to only go back 24 months and also not include the current month's data.

I tried adding:

```
AND
(st_month != '$currentMonth' AND st_year != '$currentYear')
```

but that just eliminates all records for the current year and any month matching the current month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT 
    st_year as YEAR,
    st_month as  MONTH,
    count(*) 
FROM 
    V1_Stable
WHERE 
    st_year IS NOT NULL 
    AND DATE(CONCAT(st_year, '-', st_month, '-01')) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY), INTERVAL 24 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)
AND
    st_month IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    st_year,  st_month
ORDER BY YEAR ASC, MONTH ASC;
```

Comment: That's some seriously SICK SQL. Thanks dude!

Comment: To get 24 months of data (since the current month is not included in the return set), I changed "INTERVAL 24 MONTH" to "INTERVAL 25 MONTH"...  with that it works well. Query comes back in 0.003 sec as well...

Comment: Hmmm, `DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY)` returns the last day of last month and subtracting 24 months from that should technically take you 25 months back. Even then feel free to change as your needs

Comment: The returned data went back to Sept 2013 (i.e. most recent 24 month's query), but not including the current month it should go back to August 2013...

Comment: yes you are right, it returns 2013-08-31 whereas it should be 2013-08-01. Using `INTERVAL 25 MONTH` will return 2013-07-31 which is one day more than the 25 months you need. if you need to fix that add a day by using `DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY), INTERVAL 25 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` which gives 2013-08-01

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing this is by converting the year/month columns into a number of months count.  This allows you to do the calculation without involving dates.  The relevant part of the `where` clause is:

```
where st_year * 12 + st_month >= year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) - 24
```

EDIT:

If you don't want the current month, then just use the same logic:

```
where st_year * 12 + st_month >= year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) - 24 and
      st_year * 12 + st_month < year(now()) * 12 + month(now())
```